# How to use "a" or "any" in a question with "is / are there?"

Tags: determiners, quantifiers

Is there a difference in meaning and if so which one between:
"Is there A teacher's desk in your classroom?" and
"Is there ANY teacher's desk in your classroom?"
and between:
"Is there PAPER in your study?" and
"Is there ANY paper in your study?"
concerning an object that is expected to be found at some place?
And also, between:
"Are there POSTERS on the walls of your kitchen?" and
"Are there ANY posters on the walls of your kitchen?"

Comment: ... for an object that can only possibly be at some place?

Comment: *Do you have **any** X?* asks whether you have ***one or more*** X's (as opposed to ***none***). But if the asker only wants ***one*** (or if it's unlikely or irrelevant that you'd have more than one), he'll probably just ask *Do you have **an** X?* Hence it's usually *Do you have a match?*, rather than *Do you have any matches?*

Answer (score 2):

The question

> Is there a teacher’s desk in that classroom?

is slightly ambiguous, at least in the absence of context. It may be asking whether there is exactly one such desk in that classroom or whether there is one or more.

> Is there any teacher’s desk in that classroom?

unambiguously asks whether there is at least one such desk in that classroom.

I stress that the ambiguity in the first question is slight and would likely be non-existent given sufficient context. Most people will probably interpret both questions as asking whether there is at least one. But if I were working with an attorney to compile a list of interrogatories, I’d avoid any possibility of ambiguity by asking

> How many teacher’s desks were in that classroom?

Comment: How about "Is there chalk in the classroom? / paper in your study??" and "Is there ANY chalk in the classroom? / paper in your study?"

Comment: How about "a" or "any" before an uncountable noun in such questions?

Comment: "Is there water in the pitcher?" means the same thing as "Is there any water in the pitcher?"

Comment: However, "is there any water?" sounds more usual to me, "Is there water?" a bit strange, doesn't it?

Comment: If you compare “is there any water” and “is there water” on ngram, you will see that they were almost equally common from 1920 to 2000.